# MYSQL+PHP, Como somar itens de tabelas diferentes SUM()?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu possuo duas tabelas:

**tabela_itens**

```
| id | descricao                 | quantidade |
| 1  | Maquina Prensa            | 1          |
| 2  | Maquina Secadora          | 2          |
```

**tabela_bom_itens**

```
| id | id_itens | codigo | quantidade |
| 1  | 1        | mp001  | 1          |
| 2  | 1        | mp002  | 2          |
| 3  | 1        | fx001  | 1          |
| 4  | 1        | fx002  | 5          |
| 5  | 2        | ms001  | 1          |
| 6  | 2        | ms002  | 2          |
| 7  | 2        | ms003  | 1          |
| 8  | 2        | ms004  | 1          |
| 9  | 2        | fx001  | 4          |
| 10 | 2        | fx002  | 1          |
```

Estou realizando a seguinte consulta:

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(tb.quantidade*quantidade)
FROM
    tabela_bom_itens
GROUP BY
    codigo;
```

O que é para acontecer a `tabela_itens` é o produto pai, e na `tabela_bom_itens` seriam os filhos.
Na `tabela_bom_itens` seria a quantidade de peças que vai para cada item pai.
Então para saber a quantidade de peças que vai no produto pai era multiplicar a quantidade de produto pai para cada produto filho, e, se aparecer o mesmo itens nos dois, agrupar e informar o valor da soma dos itens.

O resultado esperado é:

```
| codigo | quantidade |
| mp001  | 1          |
| mp002  | 2          |
| ms001  | 2          |
| ms002  | 4          |
| ms003  | 2          |
| ms004  | 2          |
| fx001  | 9          |
| fx002  | 10         |
```

Mas o que está retornando não tem nada a ver, o que tem de errado na minha consulta?

Comment: Junção, soma e agrupamento. Esses são os conceitos que são necessários para a resposta de sua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Observação: tenho uma limitação de não ter um MySQL disponível para testar, então estou fazendo os testes no SQLite; então, se alguma sintaxe estiver incorreta, favor me corrigir/me notificar

Para saber a relação entre produtos pai e produtos **bom** filhos, precisamos fazer uma junção. Então, para eu associar todos as linhas de `tabela_bom_itens` com as linhas de `tabela_itens`, faço uma junção interna:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tabela_itens pai
    INNER JOIN tabela_bom_itens filho
        ON (pai.id = filho.id_itens)
```

A junção interna é indicada pela sintaxe `INNER JOIN`. Quando se faz uma junção, é sempre bom dizer qual a condição de junção. No caso, a condição de junção é quando o `id` do pai for igual ao `id_itens` do filho. Essa condição de junção é indicada na parte `ON (pai.id = filho.id_itens)`.

Fazer a multiplicação para saber quanto de cada peça filho vai para o produto pai (ainda sem agrupar), é fazer a seguinte multiplicação:

```sql
SELECT
    pai.quantidade * filho.quantidade as quantidade_multiplicada,
    *
FROM
    tabela_itens pai
    INNER JOIN tabela_bom_itens filho
        ON (pai.id = filho.id_itens)
```

Note que a primeira coluna (identificada por `quantidade_multiplicada`) é o valor desejado de para se somar. Agora, precisamos somar essa multiplicação, agrupando por `codigo`:

```sql
SELECT
    filho.codigo,
    SUM(pai.quantidade * filho.quantidade) as quantidade_venda
FROM
    tabela_itens pai
    INNER JOIN tabela_bom_itens filho
        ON (pai.id = filho.id_itens)
GROUP BY filho.codigo
```

Na coluna `quantidade_venda`, temos o quanto de cada item foi vendido.

No caso, creio que o resultado esperado tenha um equívoco para o produto `fx002`, pois temos que ele foi vendido 5 vezes para o item `Maquina Prensa` (multiplicador de quantidade 1) e 1 vez para o item `Maquina Secadora` (multiplicador de quantidade 2), o que resultaria em 7.

Eis o resultado da minha consulta:

```sql
| codigo | quantidade_venda |
| fx001  | 9                |
| fx002  | 7                |
| mp001  | 1                |
| mp002  | 2                |
| ms001  | 2                |
| ms002  | 4                |
| ms003  | 2                |
| ms004  | 2                |
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, valeu.